# -Not as straightforward as in this fiddle?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

In the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/KvwGw/21/, when you submit the form, a new form appears, and also the background color changes.

On a wordpress blog, I'm trying to change the background image when the form is submitted. The image was uploaded to the server here

```
www.example.com/wp-content/themes/thesis_18/custom/images/strawhat.jpg
```

and then it's displayed using css (in my custom wordpress theme) like so

```
body.custom {
    background: #8db6b6 url('images/subway.jpg') repeat; 
}
```

In my stupidity, I initially tried to make the background image change unsuccessfully using the code below, but because the background image is uploaded to the server, I now realize/think some Ajax is required to change the background image on submit, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it

Does anyone know how I would make the ajax call to do this?

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $(".contactform").hide(1000,function(){
        $(".contactforms").css({display:"block"});
        $("body.custom").css({background: "url('images/strawhat.jpg') repeat;"});
    });
  });

$("#send").click(function(){
    $(".contactforms").hide(1000)
        });
```

**UPDATE**
I tried this (writing out the path), following the suggestion of the first responder, but it didn't work.

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $(".contactform").hide(1000,function(){
        $(".contactforms").css({display:"block"});
        $("body.custom").css({background: "url('/wp-content/themes/thesis_18/custom/images/strawhat.jpg') repeat;"});

    });
  });

$("#send").click(function(){
    $(".contactforms").hide(1000)
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the image path.

In the original CSS file, the path specified is relative to that CSS file. So the CSS file is at `www.example.com/wp-content/themes/thesis_18/custom/`, then specifying `'images/subway.jpg'` as the image URL will load it from `www.example.com/wp-content/themes/thesis_18/custom/images/subway.jpg`.

However, when you alter the style using JQuery, your new style is not being set in a CSS file, so its URL is not relative to that stylesheet.

I would imagine that you would need to set the background image URL relative to the main page, as there's no other context that it can be relative to at run-time. I would suggest that the best way would be to use a fully qualified path from the root of your domain, starting with a backslash, like so:

```
$("body.custom").css({background: "url('/wp-content/themes/thesis_18/custom/images/strawhat.jpg') repeat;"});
```

That will force it to get the right image.

Hope that helps explain things.

[EDIT] With regards to the comment by the OP, stating he still can't get it to work:

Assuming all your paths are correct, this should have worked. I can't prove that or explain why it didn't work without actually seeing a non-working example, but I can give you some advice on how to track down the cause of the problem.

That advice is to use Firebug. (or any of the other dev tools that come with the other browsers, but Firebug is still my favourite).

Firebug is a browser-based debugging tool, which has a several features that you may be able to use to track down the problem.

Firstly, it has a "Net" tab, which allows you to watch when HTTP requests are made, and what the results were. If you have this open when your script runs, you should see the request being made for the new image.

If you see the request being made, then you can check that it succeeded, ie not a 404 error or anything similar. This seems to me like the most likely problem. If it does throw an error, you can look at the error type and the URL that was called - if that's wrong, it should give you a big clue as to how to fix it.

If you don't see the request happening, then you can use Firebug's CSS tab to check that the stylesheet for the element has actually been updated. Again, this should give you some good avenues to investigate either way.

Next, Firebug's JS tab includes a full Javascript debugger, which allows you to put break points into your code and step through it line by line.

If all that fails, post a link to a version of your page that doesn't work, and I'll see if I can work it out from there.

[EDIT] Finally found it:

```
$("body.custom").css({background: "url('/wp-content/themes/thesis_18/custom/images/strawhat.jpg') repeat;"});
```

In the line above, the problem is that the semi-colon is not required inside the stylesheet string after the word `repeat`. It should be:

```
$("body.custom").css({background: "url('/wp-content/themes/thesis_18/custom/images/strawhat.jpg') repeat"});
```

Heh. Easy one to miss.

I found this in the end by pasting the line of code above into Firebug's console, and trying different things until it worked.  :-)

Comment: o.k, the path problem makes sense now that you explain it, but I can't get it to work. I tried the code in the "update" section of the OP without any luck.  Just to make sure I understand, are you saying that the background image should change without any refresh?

Comment: @Michael - yes, it should load the new image when you change the background URL. Try watching in Firebug (or DevTools, etc), to see what HTTP requests are fired when your code runs. If the URL is changing correctly, you should see the browser fire a request to load it. See what path it actually tries to load: is it right? does it get a 404? You should get some clues from this. Also use Firebug to look at the styles of the element before and after your code runs. It's a very useful tool for debugging this kind of thing.

Comment: @Michael - okay ... I'm having a look ... just to confirm -- if I click that 'confirm' button, that's what should trigger the background to change, correct?

Comment: yes, if you click confirm (id #submit), the city form disappears and at the same time it should trigger the change in background image. The code is in the OP

Comment: I think the problem might be that the script doesn't find the element body.custom

Comment: @Michael -- okay. Found it. In your line of code where you set the CSS, you don't need the semicolon at the end of the string, ie after the word `repeat`.

Comment: thank you so much. I really appreciate it. If you ever have time/inclination, please update answer to let me know which tool helped you figure it out. I'm trying to learn from what you wrote. Thanks again.